# Can "borrow" be used like this?

Tags: word-usage

> "You have a lot of books!" A says to B, kneeling in front of B's
> bookshelf. "Do you mind if I borrow one for a bit?"

Can borrow be used here even though A is going to read the book in B's room (e.g. sitting next to B)?

I ask because I'm not sure if borrow implies that you're taking the item away from its original place.

Comment: Yes you can use borrow this way.  The verb has no restrictions as to location.

Comment: (With ***read***, "a bit" probably means "for a few minutes", but with ***borrow***, "a bit" probably means "for a few days".)

Comment: I wouldn't describe reading a book for a while in the owner's room as 'borrowing' it, just 'having a look at' it.

Comment: Borrow is as borrow does. A good idiom for you.

Answer (score 1):

As you thought, 'borrow' does imply that you want to examine or use. If you wanted to sit  down and just read it, then you'd just ask "Is it ok if I read this?"

Comment: Some dialects in the UK actually use 'borrow' sometimes in place of 'lend', as in "Can you borrow me your book?"